# check if c# function is true in javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, asp.net, sql

Ok so i have a C# function which returns true if row exists in sql table

```
System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static bool Check(string ID)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpleDB"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
                      IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Book Where Name = @ID)
                      SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return (result == 1);
            }
        }
```

and i have another Javascript function but it seems this "PageMethods.Check(btn.id)" statement is never true even if such row in the sql table exists so i guess im not checking it correctly and im wondering if the problem is in javascript or in C#

```
 function InIt(k ,l)
            {
                for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
                    for (j = 1; j <= l; j++) {
                        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                        btn.id = i + "_" + j;
                        if (PageMethods.Check(btn.id) == true) {
                            //DO SOMETHING
                        }
                        else {//DO SOMETHING ELSE 
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

PageMethods need to have a callback function like **OnSuccess** and **Onfailure**

use your OnSuccess function to check if the return value is true

like this

```
PageMethods.Check(btn.id,OnSuccess,Onfailure);
```

then in OnSuccess function

```
function OnSuccess(data)
{
if(data)
 // do something
else
 // do something else
}
```

And I hope you have set `EnablePageMethods = true` in your `<asp:ScriptManager>`

Comment: well i have my ScriptManager set and i have tried another PageMethods functions withouth OnSuccess and Onfailure and they work maybe something else is wrong

Comment: @Arch_interpreter are you able to call the C# function?

Comment: attach a debugger to your c# webmethod, and see if the function is called, also check your console to see if there are any js errors

Comment: im sorry im new in this i dont really know what do you mean to attach a debugger to my c# webmethod.

Comment: Some Basci ASP.net debugging links for @Arch_interpreter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2faa92k.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at313d3f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have EnablePageMethods attribute set true at scriptmanger. Otherwise PageMethods will not work as expected.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
```

Its working as expected by using yours code at my sandbox.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (PageMethods.Check(10) == true) {
                alert(true);
            }
            else {
                alert(false)
            }
        });
    </script>


[WebMethod]
public static bool Check(string ID)
{
    if (ID.Length > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```